# XCode style file handling in visual studio

Tags: xcode, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to let visual studio 2010/2012 behave like XCode when selecting files in the project explorer?

Although i work with VS since almost 13 years, i still really hate the fact that the selection in the project explorer is not in sync with the selected files / tabs in the document pane. You always have to check which file you have opened. In XCode you simply look at the project-tree and know where you are.

Is there an option to activate this single-click selection / single-document behaviour in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Visual Studio 2012 this is now available. Clicking a file in the solution explorer opens it immediately with a right-aligned tab. Double clicking permanently opens it, with a standard tab, aligned to the left.